# Python strptime parse timezone format "GMT+-H"

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, python-datetime, timezone-offset

I'm using python 3.7 and trying to figure out the correct format to get this code to work

```
dt = datetime.strptime("4 January 2022, 22:03 GMT-5", "%-d %b %Y, %H:%M %Zz")
```

The above line always fails. Is there something I can do to get it to parse? I am assuming its failing on the "GMT-5 part"

Edit:
Adding context, the input string is scraped from a website so I need to find a way to turn it into a python datetime object so by code can understand when the event took place. Im not really sure how I could "In Code" change the input to match the required format of strptime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%z` parsing directive won't parse an hour-only UTC offset ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes): requires ±HHMM[SS[.ffffff]] form). But you can derive a timezone object from a timedelta and set it like

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

s = "4 January 2022, 22:03 GMT-5"

parts = s.split('GMT')

dt = (datetime.strptime(parts[0].strip(), "%d %B %Y, %H:%M") # parse to datetime w/o offset
          .replace(tzinfo=timezone(timedelta(hours=int(parts[1]))))) # add UTC offset

print(dt)
# 2022-01-04 22:03:00-05:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong format for the month and invalid text for the UTC offset (it has to be four digits, as described in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)):

```py
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("4 January 2022, 22:03 GMT-0500", "%d %B %Y, %H:%M %Z%z")
datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 4, 22, 3, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=68400), 'GMT'))
```

Comment: I'll add clarification to the question, but i dont control the input string, The string is parsed from a website and Im trying to turn this into a datetime object in python so i can  place it in time. Im a bit confused how to modify the input with python commands to get it into that format. Not sure if you would be able to help with that?

Comment: @lufthansa747 that would be a separate question and depend on the range of possible values you would encounter. If the offset is always a single, you could just surround the last character with zeros.